# jQuery UI AutoComplete and jQuery Mobile - driving me mad

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it just me, but with jQuery mobile I seem to take one step forward and two steps back?

All I'm trying to do is get the autocomplete option to work. I tried using jQuery Mobile.AutoComplete and can't get it to work, so I?m trying to use jQuery ui.autocomplete.

Using Asp.net MVC, I have a shared page.

I'm desperate to get this to work, please help (don't care if using the jQuery to work mobile autocomplete option is best)....

```
<head>
   ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/UI/jqueryUI-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/Mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DateValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/JQuery/UI-TimePicker/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Then I have a menu (shared)

```
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
     <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                $("#clientSearch").autocomplete({
                    source: "@Url.Action("ClientSearch","Schedule")",
                 minLength: 3,
                 select: function (event, ui) {

                     $("#clientSearch").val(ui.item.ClientName);
                     $("#clientSearchId").val(ui.item.ClientId);

                     return false;
                 }
             }
        ).data("uiAutocomplete")
            ._renderItem = function (ul, client) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", client)
                    .append("<a>" + client.FullName + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
         });

     </script>
     <h3>Schedule</h3>
     <a href="index.html" data-icon="plus"  class="ui-btn-right"data-iconpos="notext">Appointment</a>
     <input type="hidden" id="clientSearchId"/>
     <input name="clientSearch" id="clientSearch" placeholder="" value="" type="search">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="~/Home/Index" data-transition="slide" data-theme="">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/Schedule/MobileSchedule" data-transition="slide" data-theme="">
                        Schedule
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So a page will look like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AppHomeLayout.cshtml"; 
}

<div data-role="page" id="pageHome">
    <style>
        .ui-listview-filter-inset {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    </style>

    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_MobileMenu.cshtml")
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="content"> ... </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error when loading the page:

> Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11
>   (anonymous function) jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11 b.fn.extend.domManip
>   jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11 b.fn.extend.replaceWith jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11
>   (anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 b.extend.each
>   jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 b.fn.b.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 (anonymous
>   function) jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 b.event.dispatch
>   jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 v.handle jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 b.event.trigger
>   jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 (anonymous function) jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11
>   b.extend.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 b.fn.b.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
>   b.fn.extend.trigger jquery.1.9.1.min.js:11 a.Widget._trigger
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 a.Widget._createWidget
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 a.widget._createWidget
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 (anonymous function)
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 a.(anonymous function).(anonymous
>   function) jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 (anonymous function)
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 b.extend.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
>   b.fn.b.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 a.fn.(anonymous function)
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 C jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2
>   a.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages.h.isSameDomain.a.ajax.success
>   jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js:2 c jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 p.fireWith
>   jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4 k jquery.1.9.1.min.js:19 r

Ideas? It looks like its trying to use jQuery mobile autocomplete, if anyone has a soloution\code sample to fix, it would help me out so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change the quotes inside parenthesis on this line from double to single, like this:

```
source: "@Url.Action('ClientSearch','Schedule')",
```

Comment: Try to test by replacing @Url.Action (...) with regular full path URL

Comment: I dont think its the path but the jquery files, ive tried anyway with no luck